# In JScript: Can I enumerate the methods on an object created via new ActiveXObject()?

Tags: javascript, activexobject

This is really a question for Eric Lippert, or someone at Microsoft who's familiar with the implementation of the JScript engine.

Can I do this:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("My.ProgId");
var methods = GetMethodsViaMagic(obj);
```

?

(supposing the COM type supports IDispatch)

and if so, what does `GetMethodsViaMagic()` look like?

---

**EDIT** - of course, the first thing I tried was the `for...in` loop, but that does not work for methods and properties defined on ActiveX objects.  At least, not for objects I've defined in .NET and exposed via `ComVisible`.

---

In C#, I can define IDispatch like this:

```
 [Guid("00020400-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
 public interface IDispatch
 {
     int GetTypeInfoCount();
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo
         GetTypeInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iTInfo,
                     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int lcid);

     [PreserveSig]
     int GetIDsOfNames(ref Guid riid,
                       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] rgsNames,
                       int cNames,
                       int lcid,
                       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] rgDispId);

     [PreserveSig]
     int Invoke(int dispIdMember,
                ref Guid riid,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int lcid,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags,
                ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DISPPARAMS pDispParams,
                [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] object[] pVarResult,
                ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo,
                [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] IntPtr[] pArgErr);
 }
```

Then I can do something like this:

```
    var idispatch = (IDispatch) comObject ;
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo typeInfo =
        idispatch.GetTypeInfo(0, 0);

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FUNCDESC funcDesc;
    string strName, strDocString, strHelpFile;
    int dwHelpContext;

    typeInfo.GetFuncDesc(i, out pFuncDesc);// i = 1, 2, 3...
    funcDesc = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FUNCDESC)
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(pFuncDesc,
                               typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FUNCDESC));
```

...and get function (method) names,  and the number of arguments, etc.

Can I do something like that in JScript, for an ActiveX (COM IDispatch) object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that I haven't worked on JScript for over a decade now; the engine has changed in that time and my memory has faded.

To the best of my recollection and knowledge: The for-in loop will work if the object implements IDispatchEx, but not if the object just implements IDispatch.

I always wanted to add a mechanism such that JScript programs could use information available from the type info associated with the dispatch object to enumerate the properties, but I don't believe I ever actually wrote the code.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, Mr Lippert. It would be handy to have the feature you described. Can't imagine that adding the feature now would break many programs. I understand Win8 is getting more Javascript Love; looks very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

What I found is that I can use the Javascript `for...in` loop, to enumerate the methods and properties, *if I have implemented IReflect on the ComVisible .NET object*.

[IReflect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ireflect.aspx) is marshaled as IDispatch across the CCW.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. The `for..in` loop does not work for a com-visible, IReflect-based class. The only reason why not seems to be Eric's answer above; that is, it needs an IDispatchEx interface (whereas IReflect only implements IDispatch, as described in your link).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
var methods = [];
for( var property in obj ) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof obj[property] === 'function' ) {
        methods.push(property);
    }
}
```

the `methods` array will then contain the method names. If the object in question is an instance of some constructor, you might want to drop the `hasOwnProperty` check, as that restricts everything to only look at properties/methods that are defined on the obj itself, not those in its prototype chain.

As for the number of arguments, you can use (as Domenic points out in the comments) [the `.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of the function itself.

So to get both name and number of arguments for every method in `obj`:

```
var methods = [];
for( var property in obj ) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof obj[property] === 'function' ) {
        methods.push({
            name: property,
            args: obj[property].length
        });
    }
}
```

And you'll get an array of object literals, each containing the name and the number of arguments of a method from `obj`.

---

Edit: I was thinking about getting the *names* (rather than simply the number) of arguments, when I first wrote this answer, and thus included some fairly hacky code to get those names. In case anyone's interested, here's the code for that, which I just <strike>shamelessly stole</strike> adapted from [Prototype.js](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/argumentNames/))

```
function argumentNames(func) {
  var names = func.toString().match(/^[\s\(]*function[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/)[1]
    .replace(/\/\/.*?[\r\n]|\/\*(?:.|[\r\n])*?\*\//g, '')
    .replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',');
  return names.length == 1 && !names[0] ? [] : names;
}
```

Pass a function/method to that function, and it'll give you back the argument names… *maybe*. If the object you get back is a fully-fledged host object, its methods/functions may not be readable by `toString()`. Usually, `toString()` will return the actual source code of the method/function (and the `argumentNames` function parses that with some regex), but in the case of native code, you may just get the string "native code" or something back, rather than the source code.

Comment: You can get the number of arguments of a function via the `length` property of the function object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Comment: Domenic: Of course, you're right - I was thinking about argument _names_ for some reason. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Expecting Microsoft's ActiveX objects to implement features of Netscape's JavaScript or ECMAScript is drawing a long bow. Do not be surprised it fails, or throws an error.

Comment: @RobG: True enough… but getting the method names with the `for…in`-loop should work though. But yeah, I don't know about the other stuff…

Comment: Flambino and RobG: Whoops - I was tired whern I wrote the question.  I should have mentioned that I tried the `for..in` loop, and it does not work for COM objects.

Comment: @Cheeso: Ah, too bad. I naïvely thought that COM/ActiveX notwithstanding, a JS object would still be, well, a JS object. I should've known better; it's IE after all. Sigh… I should have listened to RobG :P